# Variables have different lifetimes, when they should have the same

Tags: rust

To learn Rust, I am writing a [library](https://github.com/Monnoroch/RustJni) wrapping JNI. I have encountered lots of lifetime issues and fought the compiler bravely to resolve them, but with this one I just give up. Here's the problem.

Now, JNI is the interface to Java virtual machine, so every java object has to be tied to the VM. In order to do that, I have created th "VM pointer" type JavaVM, which is mostly just a wrapper for the pointer and an interface for creating JavaEnv objects, which are just wrappers for JNIEnv*, and also providers of a safer interface for most of JNI methods.

In order to declare that JavaEnv object is tied to the VM I did the following:

```rust
pub struct JavaEnv<'a> {
    phantom: PhantomData<&'a JavaVM>,
    ...
}
```

Now, if I understand correctly, all JavaEnv objects will be tied to some JavaVM object by the lifetime, and will not outlive it, which is exactly what I want.

JavaEnv -- is an interface for manipulating java objects (and some other stuff). Now, all types of JNI objects implement a trait:

```rust
pub trait JObject<'a>: Drop {
    fn get_env(&self) -> &'a JavaEnv<'a>;
    ...
}
```

and themselves all look like this:

```rust
pub struct JavaObject<'a> {
    env: &'a JavaEnv<'a>,
    ...
}

pub struct JavaClass<'a> {
    env: &'a JavaEnv<'a>,
    ...
}
```

Now, if again I understand correctly, all JavaObject-s will be tied to some JavaEnv object by the lifetime, which in turn is tied to a JavaVM object.

Finally, Java is the language with default reference semantics, so object comparison is just a shallow reference comparison and I wanted to reflect it in the Rust interface:

```rust
impl<'a, R: 'a + JObject<'a>> PartialEq<R> for JavaObject<'a> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &R) -> bool {
        self.get_env().is_same_object(self, other)
    }
}

impl<'a, R: 'a + JObject<'a>> PartialEq<R> for JavaClass<'a> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &R) -> bool {
        self.get_env().is_same_object(self, other)
    }
}

pub fn JavaEnv::is_same_object<T1: 'a + JObject<'a>, T2: 'a + JObject<'a>>(&self, obj1: &T1, obj2: &T2) -> bool {
    unsafe {
        ((**self.ptr).IsSameObject)(self.ptr, obj1.get_obj(), obj2.get_obj()) == JNI_TRUE
    }
}
```

This doesn't work. Here's a test:

```rust
let (cls, cap) = JavaClass::find(&env, "java/lang/String", cap).unwrap();
let (obj /*of class java/lang/String*/, cap) = cls.alloc(cap).unwrap();
let cls1 /*also java/lang/String*/ = obj.get_class(&cap);
assert!(cls1 == cls); 
let (sobj /*also of java/lang/String*/, cap) = JavaString::new(&env, "hi!", cap).unwrap();
assert!(cls1 != sobj);
let scls /*also java/lang/String*/ = sobj.get_class(&cap);
assert!(scls == cls1);
assert!(scls == cls);
// TODO: somehow these cls1, scls and cls have different lifetimes (or not?)
// So those two asserts do not compile!!
assert!(cls1 == scls);
assert!(cls == scls);
```

To "fix" this I had to change the eq code:

```rust
impl<'a, 'b, R: 'b + JObject<'b>> PartialEq<R> for JavaObject<'a> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &R) -> bool {
        self.get_env().is_same_object(self, other)
    }
}

impl<'a, 'b, R: 'b + JObject<'b>> PartialEq<R> for JavaClass<'a> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &R) -> bool {
        self.get_env().is_same_object(self, other)
    }
}

pub fn JavaEnv::is_same_object<'b, T1: 'a + JObject<'a>, T2: 'b + JObject<'b>>(&self, obj1: &T1, obj2: &T2) -> bool {
    unsafe {
        ((**self.ptr).IsSameObject)(self.ptr, obj1.get_obj(), obj2.get_obj()) == JNI_TRUE
    }
}
```

But I DON'T want to compare JObjects attached to different VM's!
And, even more: I just don't get, how those objects ended up having different lifetime parameters? They all were obtained from the same JavaEnv and hence the same JavaVM!

So, the questions are: what did I do wrong, why this is happening and how to fix this?

Comment: Is it true that all asserts except the last two compile?

Comment: It's hard to dig into this because you provided only part of the implementation (which is understandable, given the complexity). Not sure this will help, but: does `get_class()` return something of lifetime `'a` ? Alternatively, maybe you could consider annotating as follows: `T1: 'aa + JObject<'a>, T2: 'bb + JObject<'b>`  and specify `where 'a: 'aa, 'b: 'bb`? (`:` means "outlives")

Comment: Here I thought that JVM uses a singleton pattern and you can get it from anywhere with `getjvm` or something. A cursory googling seems to support that: http://database.developer-works.com/article/15552998/Multiple+JVM+instances

Comment: @delnan, yes, it's true.

Comment: @ArtemGr, this is why I provided a link to the code: it's not that big and complicated.
``fn get_class(&'a self, _cap: &Capability) -> JavaClass<'a>;``
Everywhere through the code I pass 'a lifetime from JavaEnv to children objects.

Comment: @monnoroch, It's certainly simpler than sourceforge.net/projects/jvm-bridge/ which I tacked some years back, but I can't take a look now, sorry. Passing lifetimes could be a bitch. Can't you just return an error if someone uses a method without initializing the JVM first? You could even `panic!`, since this is something that shouldn't happen if the code logic is intact. Sounds to me like you're trying to emulate the wrong abstractions: JVM is a global thread-safe singleton but you're trying to tell the Rust borrowchecker that it's something local.

Comment: Please be considerate when asking questions on Stack Overflow. Your example code doesn't even state the errors you are getting, just that it "doesn't compile". It's also overly complex. You ask us to go to a third-party site to get your code to fix it for you. Take the time to produce a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This can help you understand the problem or produce a laser-focused example that we can grasp quickly.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your basic premise has an issue. Check out this example code:

```rust
fn are_equal<'a>(a: &'a u8, b: &'a u8) -> bool {
    *a == *b
}

fn main() {
    let a = 42;

    {
        let b = 84;
        println!("{}", are_equal(&a, &b));
    }
}
```

Here, we have a method that takes two reference arguments with the lifetime parameter `'a`. However, you can clearly see that the actual lifetimes of `a` and `b` (in `main`) are **not the same** — `a` outlives `b` due to the block ending.

All that is required is that there is *some lifetime* that can unify both parameters, and there is - the scope of the inner block. It doesn't mean that the entire lifetime has to be exactly equal.